Current thinking on whether isolating languages have more complex syntax, or pragmatics, or lexicon, or other features
I'm wondering what the current thinking is on whether isolating languages really do have more complicated syntax or pragmatics or leixcons or other features than non-isolating ones.
I found an interesting paper that outlines an experiment with simple sentences in isolating languages and pictures which appears to show that isolating languages are a heterogeneous bunch, some of which assign consistent interpretations to argument positions, like Papiamentu and some don't, like Minangkabau. And this argues against the Compensation Hypothesis (defined below).
The paper itself says explicitly that the Compensation Hypothesis is the received wisdom and I'm curious whether that's still true, since the paper was written in 2008.

The Compensation Hypothesis is the idea that across their domains, in aggregate, languages are approximately equally complex.
The background section for this paper by David Gil from 2008 describes it this way in the background section.

The received view amongst linguists is that all languages are of equal complexity: there is no such thing as a simple language or a more complex one.

And provides a well-known example of an instance of the received wisdom theory, namely the Romance languages becoming less syntactically flexible as sound change eroded their case endings.

What  this  shows,  then, is  that  in  the  history  of  the  Romance languages, the burden of differentiating thematic roles has shifted from the morphology to the syntax.

The paper also mentions some previous empirical work by Siewierska (I think this is the same person as Anna Siewierska, who has written a few of the feature descriptions on WALS) that shows some statistically-significant-but-weak correspondence between case marking and word-order flexibiltiy. Weak enough to suggest that a general compensatory mechanism perhaps does not exist.

As  evident  from  Siewierska's  study,  there  are  simply  too  many counterexamples  in  both  directions—"fussy  languages"  with  redundant marking of semantic distinctions in both the morphology and the syntax, as well  as  "carefree  languages" that  do  not  mark  these  distinctions  in either domain—for such a compensatory mechanism to be attributed a  significant role in determining linguistic structure.

From what I can gather from reading the paper, the experiment outlined shows a sentence in an isolating language like bird eat and then shows some pictures, one of which is a cat eating a bird for example, and asks participants to determine whether the sentence describes the picture. And the experiment has uncovered more and less flexible isolating languages.
I especially like this comment about claiming that the pragmatics picks up the slack.

In practical terms, when linguists say things like "the grammar doesn't encode  it,  so  speakers  have  to  figure  it  out  from  the  context",  the  "it" in question is, more often than not, a distinction that is  absent from the target language but one that the linguist expects to find, because it is prominent in English  and  other  European  languages. The  mistake  is to assume that this absence is a lacuna that needs somehow to be filled in by the pragmatics: in most cases, there is no such need whatsoever.

